# React: Call a function from a non-owner parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know you can pass event handlers into children that are explicitly rendered by an owner component, like this:

```
var Owner = React.createClass({
    eventHandler: function() {
        console.log("Interaction!");
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input onChange={this.eventHandler}/>
                <button onClick={this.eventHandler}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

But what if I wanted to pass these functions from a parent component to its nested `this.props.children`?

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
    eventHandler: function() {
        console.log("Interaction!");
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <span>
                {this.props.children}
            </span>
        );
    }
});
var Owner = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Parent>
                    <input onChange={whatDoIPutHere}/>
                    <button onClick={orDoIPutThisInTheParentIDK}/>
                </Parent>
             </div>
         );
});
```

I got something working by doing this:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
    eventHandler: function() {
        console.log("Interaction!");
    },
    render: function() {
        var newChildren = this.props.children.map(child => {
            var newProps = {};
            if (child.type === 'input') {
                newProps.onChange = this.eventHandler;
            } else if (child.type === 'button') {
                newProps.onClick = this.eventHandler;
            }
            return React.cloneElement(child, newProps);
        });
        return (
            <span>
                {newChildren}
            </span>
        );
    }
});
```

But that requires me to hard-code which element types to look for, and which prop to pass `eventHandler` to. I want to be able to specify all that in the `<Owner>` component, and have `<Parent>` just be a generic container that's agnostic to how exactly its `eventHandler` gets called.

Is there any way to do this? I'd like to avoid any workarounds like `getDOMNode()`, because I'm expecting this codebase might be shared with React Native in the future.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you give a better description of the problem this solves?

Comment: I'm trying to create a component that passes the data inside its child element to a central data store (we're kind of using a Backbone-model-as-Flux in this project). That child element could be an input box, a select element, a radio button, etc. It's also supposed to contain some functions to highlight it if it's invalid, empty, etc. when the user tries to click Submit. Right now we have to lay plumbing through every level of the form component, so I'm trying to encapsulate the data binding/required field stuff in a simple wrapper component to avoid that.

Comment: __opinion:__ If you're trying to write sane forms in React, you basically can't. The 1-way data flow is counter to the very notion of taking user data.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to use the same handler for a button click _and_ a change event. Those seem completely orthagonal.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just generalize the different interaction methods, and just pass the type of interaction back up to the handler? Something like:

```
var cloned = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function (c) {
    return React.cloneElement(c, {
      onChange: this.props.onInteraction.bind(this, 'change'),
      onClick: this.props.onInteraction.bind(this, 'click')
    });
}, this);
```

That way you get notified of all clicks and changes (other types of interaction could be added to the list, too, like `onKeyUp`, `onMouseMove`, etc)

[Link to jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/salale/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

Based on rossipedia's answer, I figured this out:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
    eventHandler: function() {
        console.log("Interaction!");
    },
    render: function() {
        var newChildren = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
            var newProps = {};
            for (var i in child.props) {
                if (child.props[i] === "onInteraction") {
                    newProps[i] = this.eventHandler;
                }
            }
            return React.cloneElement(child, newProps);
        });
        return (
            <span>
                {newChildren}
            </span>
        );
    }
});
```

which allows me to do  this:

```
<Parent>
    <input onChange="onInteraction"/>
</Parent>
```

Not super elegant, but it works. Might be able to figure out something better with parent-based context once React 0.14 hits.